# new socket.io 1.0 client trying to connect on a wrong port

Tags: socket.io-1.0

when trying to upgrade my website and (nodejs + express + socket.io server) from socket.io 0.9 to 1.0, immediatelly ran into a problem: socket.io client is trying to connect not on the prort where socket.io server is listening, but on the port where the webpage which is using the client is running on.
needless to say - everything is running FOR YEARS on socket.io 0.9 with no problems...

so, specifically (everything is running on localhost):
-- node.js server:

```
var app = express();
var svr = http.Server(app);
require('socket.io').listen(svr);
svr.listen(3000);
```

-- index.html (serving on port 80 by another node.js process):

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>

<script>
   var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
   socket.on('test', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
   });
</script>
```

-- when i run this web page in chrome, i see error message in chrome js console (the message repeats every second or so):

```
**GET http://localhost:80/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1401472842589-6 404 (Not Found) socket.io.js?_dc=1401472822276:2604**
```

as you can see, socket.io client library is trying to connect to the socket server on the same port, as the web page is running on - port 80 - instead of using websocket port - port 3000.

again, when i run identical code using socket.io version 0.9 - everything works.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

You are configuring wrong way, when you are using express then for a now time syntax has been changed for newer version for socket.io 1.0. same syntax like express middleware.

Please user.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(3000);
```

WRONG PART in code

> ```
> require('socket.io').listen(svr);
> ```

Comment: The problem was in the client, why would changing the server side code help?